# How to solve TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable in Python

Tags: python, typeerror

This is my function which throws this error

```
   TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

in line:

```
   if all(v == 0):
```

My goal is in this line to check whether all values are equal to Zero.

Here is my method:

```
def main():


  def checklist( thelist ):
    if len(thelist) > 2:
        for v in thelist: 
            if v < 0.0: 
                print ("One negative")
            if all(v == 0):
                print( "All zero")
            else:
                print("All good")  

alist = [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.0]
checklist( alist ) 




if __name__ == '__main__':
 
# Calling main() function
    main()
```

What I do not understand is what am I actually checking with this line as I'm apparently not checking my list.

Edited code:

```
  def checklist( thelist ):
    if len(thelist) > 2:
        for v in thelist: 
            if v < 0.0: 
                print ("One negative")
        if all(vs == 0 for vs in thelist):
            print( "All zero")
        else:
            print("All good")  

alist = [0.0, -0.1, 0.3, 0.0]
checklist( alist )
```

Comment: `all(vs == 0 for vs in thelist)` - but do not put that into the `for` loop.

Comment: You are checking for `v`, which is an item of the list. So `v==0` is a `bool`. Just drop the for loop.

Comment: Thank you! @luk2302
It works but I want to reach that I can check both "no value negative" and "at least one not none" before returning the else: So I modified it to the code I have edited in my question but now it prints: "One negativ" and "all good". How can I change it that it only prints "one negative" with the given list?

Comment: Maybe I did not explicitly mention my goal. I want to print "all good" if and only if all values are not negative AND at least one value is not zero. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():


  def checklist( thelist ):
    if len(thelist) > 2:
        if all(vs == 0.0 for vs in thelist):
            print( "All zero")
        if any(v < 0.0 for v in thelist): 
            print ("At least one negative")
        else:
            print("All good")  

alist = [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
checklist( alist )
```

Solved it! Thanks to @luk2302

Answer (score 2):

The `all` method expects an iterable.

In your example, `v` is a float and `v == 0` is a boolean. So you're trying to call `all` for a boolean value, which isn't allowed and leads to the `TypeError` you're getting.

To check that all values are the 0, you can do it in the following manner:

```
all(v == 0 for v in alist)
```